How to fetch LinkedIn posts including posts with videos through linkedin-api
I am trying to fetch LinkedIn shares through this endpoint:
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:organization:0123456

This returns all the posts, except the posts with a video. I can not find it in the documentation.
Anyone knows how to also fetch the posts including videos?
